# Delete rows of Dataframe based on multiple conditions from different Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two large Dataframes. The first one contains data, consisting of a date column and a location column, followed by several data column. The second DataFrame consists of a date column and a location column. I want to remove all the rows where the date and the location of df1 match df2.

I have tried a few ways to fix this, including drop statements, drop statements within for loops and redefining the dataframe based on multiple conditions. They all don't  work

```
date = pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-03'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
location = [1,2,1,2,1,2]
nr = [8,10,15,2,20,38]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','location','nr'])
df1['date']=date
df1['location']=location
df1['nr']=nr
```

this results in the following dataframe:

```
        date  location  nr
0 2019-01-01         1   8
1 2019-01-01         2  10
2 2019-01-02         1  15
3 2019-01-02         2   2
4 2019-01-03         1  20
5 2019-01-03         2  38
```

the second dataframe:

```
date2 = pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01','2019-01-02'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
location2 = [2,1]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','location'])
df2['date']=date2
df2['location']=location2
```

resulting in the following dataframe:

```
  date  location
0 2019-01-01         2
1 2019-01-02         1
```

then the drop statement:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
     dayA = df2['date'].iloc[i]
     placeA = df2['location'].iloc[i]
     df1.drop(df1.loc[(df1['date']==dayA)& (df1['location']==placeA)],inplace=True)
```

which results in this case in the error code in the example :
KeyError: "['date' 'location' 'nr'] not found in axis"
However in my larger dataframe it results in the error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

what I need however is

```
        date  location  nr
0 2019-01-01         1   8
3 2019-01-02         2   2
4 2019-01-03         1  20
5 2019-01-03         2  38
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df1.loc[(df1['date']==dayA)& (df1['location']==placeA)]` is the *dataframe* consisting of rows where the date and location match. `drop` is expecting the *index* where they match. So you need `df1.loc[(df1['date']==dayA)& (df1['location']==placeA)].index`. However, this is a very inefficient method. You can use `merge` instead as the other answers discuss. Another method would be `df1 = df1.loc[~df1[['date','location']].apply(tuple,axis=1).isin(zip(df2.date,df2.location))]`.

Comment: that last line did the trick. The merges were confusing with date indices, or returning empty dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas merge:
This should work

```
df1['index_col'] = df1.index
df = df1.merge(df2,on=['date','location'],how='left')
df = df.dropna()
df = df[df1.columns]

result_df = df1[~df.index_col.isin(df1.index_col)]
```

Comment: I think there is no `left outer` merge in pandas

Comment: Pandas only has ‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, default ‘inner’.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas `merge` and a little trick:

```py
df2['temp'] = 2
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['date', 'location'])
df = df[pd.isna(df.temp)]
del df['temp']
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line:

```
df1.drop(df1.loc[(df1['date']==dayA)& (df1['location']==placeA)],inplace=True)
```

You can achieve your target like this:

```
df1 = df1.loc[~((df1['date']==dayA) & (df1['location']==placeA))]
```

Basically, everytime you find a match for each row, you essentially remove it from the `df1` dataframe.

Output:

```
        date  location  nr
0 2019-01-01         1   8
3 2019-01-02         2   2
4 2019-01-03         1  20
5 2019-01-03         2  38
```